# Add parameters to url using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, url-parameters, getelementsbyclassname

I would like to **add url parameter** to my `img src`, can do it using `getElementById` but can't using `getElementsByClassName`. I'd prefer using `getElementsByClassName` as it would make more sense for my purpose. Here is the code I am using:

```
<img id="parameter" src="http://url-to-image.com/image.jpg" style="width: 100%">

<script>
var image = document.getElementById("parameter");
var imageSrc = image.getAttribute("src");
image.setAttribute("src", imageSrc + "?w=" + viewportWidth + "&h=" + viewportHeight + "&dpr=" + dpr + "&fit=crop");
</script>
```

The code above works great, but using

```
<img class="parameter" src="http://url-to-image.com/image.jpg" style="width: 100%">

<script>
var image = document.getElementsByClassName("parameter");
var imageSrc = image.getAttribute("src");
image.setAttribute("src", imageSrc + "?w=" + viewportWidth + "&h=" + viewportHeight + "&dpr=" + dpr + "&fit=crop");
</script>
```

doesn't add anything to the `img src`. The url parameter shall be added to all images with the class "parameter". Would be glad if someone could help me on this.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` always returns a **list** of elements, even if there's just one element with the class. You have to operate on each element in the list separately.

Comment: getElementById returns a single element only, all the getElementsBy… methods however return a node list, that you have to loop over, to access the individual elements on it.

Comment: Thanks for all your posts, now that makes sense. The url parameter shall be added to all images with the class "parameter", I have added that information to my question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array and so you need to either loop over all elements or if you are sure to only having one element, you can select the first element with `[0]` after `image`.

If you want to apply it to all images, you can loop over them. In the following example I'm using `querySelectorAll` to select the class `.parameter`.

```js
const viewportWidth = '100px';
const viewportHeight = '100px';
const dpr = 2;

const images = document.querySelectorAll(".parameter");
images.forEach( ( image ) => {
  const imageSrc = image.getAttribute("src");
  image.setAttribute("src", imageSrc + "?w=" + viewportWidth + "&h=" + viewportHeight + "&dpr=" + dpr + "&fit=crop");
} );
```

```html
<img class="parameter" src="http://url-to-image.com/image.jpg" style="width: 100%">
```

Comment: Thanks for your support! The parameters should be added to all images with the "parameter" class.

Comment: Thanks, nice on as well!

Answer (score 5):

As other guys said, [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), return list always.
I think you can take a look at the [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method instead.

```
var image = document.querySelector(".parameter");
```

then you don't need to look at the first item in list.

**Performance**
in a performance perspective, getElementByClass would be faster. [Performance test](https://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-getelementsbyclassname/8)

Comment: This one works best for my purpose. Thanks all for your help and support!

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one element with class name `parameter`, use it with index 0,

```
var image = document.getElementsByClassName("parameter")[0];
```

The [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) method of Document interface returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names